# Can I use a different corpus for fasttext build_vocab than train in Gensim Fasttext?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, word-embedding, fasttext

I am curious to know if there are any implications of using a different source while calling the `build_vocab` and `train` of Gensim `FastText` model. Will this impact the contextual representation of the word embedding?

My intention for doing this is that there is a specific set of words I am interested to get the vector representation for and when calling `model.wv.most_similar`. I only want words defined in this vocab list to get returned rather than all possible words in the training corpus. I would use the result of this to decide if I want to group those words to be relevant to each other based on similarity threshold.

Following is the code snippet that I am using, appreciate your thoughts if there are any concerns or implication with this approach.

- vocab.txt contains a list of unique words of interest
- corpus.txt contains full conversation text (i.e. chat messages) where each line represents a paragraph/sentence per chat

A follow up question to this is what values should I set for `total_examples` & `total_words` during training in this case?

```
from gensim.models.fasttext import FastText

model = FastText(min_count=1, vector_size=300,)

corpus_path = f'data/{client}-corpus.txt'
vocab_path = f'data/{client}-vocab.txt'
# Unsure if below counts should be based on the training corpus or vocab
corpus_count = get_lines_count(corpus_path)
total_words = get_words_count(corpus_path)

# build the vocabulary
model.build_vocab(corpus_file=vocab_path)

# train the model
model.train(corpus_file=corpus.corpus_path, epochs=100, 
    total_examples=corpus_count, total_words=total_words,
)

# save the model
model.save(f'models/gensim-fastext-model-{client}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase someone has similar question, I'll paste the reply I got when asking this question in the [Gensim Disussion Group](https://groups.google.com/d/msgid/gensim/e1330c28-e5df-4494-9bdb-bc1eaccd18dfn%40googlegroups.com?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer) for reference:

> You can try it, but I wouldn't expect it to work well for most
> purposes.
>
> The `build_vocab()` call establishes the known vocabulary of the
> model, & caches some stats about the corpus.
>
> If you then supply another corpus – & especially one with *more* words
> – then:
>
> - You'll want your `train()` parameters to reflect the actual size of your training corpus. You'll want to provide a true `total_examples` and `total_words` count that are accurate for the training-corpus.
> - Every word in the training corpus that's not in the know vocabulary is ignored completely, as if it wasn't even there. So you might as
>   well filter your corpus down to just the words-of-interest first, then
>   use that same filtered corpus for both steps. Will the example texts
>   still make sense? Will that be enough data to train meaningful,
>   generalizable word-vectors for just the words-of-interest, alongside
>   other words-of-interest, without the full texts? (You could look at
>   your pref-filtered corpus to get a sense of that.) I'm not sure - it
>   could depend on how severely trimming to just the words-of-interest
>   changed the corpus. In particular, to train high-dimensional dense
>   vectors – as with `vector_size=300` – you need a lot of varied data.
>   Such pre-trimming might thin the corpus so much as to make the
>   word-vectors for the words-of-interest far less useful.
>
> You could certainly try it both ways – pre-filtered to just your
> words-of-interest, or with the full original corpus – and see which
> works better on downstream evaluations.
>
> More generally, if the concern is training time with the full corpus,
> there are likely other ways to get an adequate model in an acceptable
> amount of time.
>
> If using `corpus_file` mode, you can increase `workers` to equal the
> local CPU core count for a nearly-linear speedup from number of cores.
> (In traditional `corpus_iterable` mode, max throughput is usually
> somewhere in the 6-12 `workers` threads, as long as you ahve that many
> cores.)
>
> `min_count=1` is usually a bad idea for these algorithms: they tend to
> train faster, in less memory, leaving better vectors for the remaining
> words when you discard the lowest-frequency words, as the default
> `min_count=5` does. (It's possible `FastText` can eke a little bit of
> benefit out of lower-frequency words via their contribution to
> character-n-gram-training, but I'd only ever lower the default
> `min_count` if I could confirm it was actually improving relevant
> results.
>
> If your corpus is so large that training time is a concern, often a
> more-aggressive (smaller) `sample` parameter value not only speeds
> training (by dropping many redundant high-frequency words), but ofthen
> improves final word-vector quality for downstream purposes as well (by
> letting the rarer words have relatively more influence on the model in
> the absense of the downsampled words).
>
> And again if the corpus is so large that training time is a concern,
> than `epochs=100` is likely overkill. I believe the `GoogleNews`
> vectors were trained using only 3 passes – over a gigantic corpus. A
> sufficiently large & varied corpus, with plenty of examples of all
> words all throughout, could potentially train in 1 pass – because each
> word-vector can then get more total training-updates than many epochs
> with a small corpus. (In general larger `epochs` values are more often
> used when the corpus is thin, to eke out something – not on a corpus
> so large you're considering non-standard shortcuts to speed the
> steps.)
>
> -- Gordon